# Wrong Answer with Java

Tags: java, string

I'm a student that is learning Java, and I have this code:

```
lletres = lletres.replace(lletres.charAt(2), codi.charAt(codi.indexOf(lletres.charAt(2)) + 1));
```

`lletres` is a string, and it's like this

```
lletres = "BBB"
```

The result is "CCC" and I only want to change the last B, so the result can be like this: "BBC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation for [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) should explain what happened here (I marked the relevant part in bold):

> Returns a string resulting from replacing **all occurrences** of `oldChar` in this string with `newChar`.

One way to solve it is to break the string up to the parts you want and then put it back together again. E.g.:

```
lletres =  lletres.substring(0, 2) + (char)(lletres.charAt(2) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed `replace()` will replace all the occurrences which matched.

So, instead you can make use of `replaceFirst()` which will accept the `regx`

```
lletres = lletres.replaceFirst( lletres.charAt( 2 ) + "$", (char) ( lletres.charAt( 2 ) + 1 ) + "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use StringBuilder for your purpose:

```
String lletres = "BBB";
String codi = "CCC";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(lletres);
sb.setCharAt(2, codi.charAt(codi.indexOf(lletres.charAt(2)) + 1));
lletres = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change only the last occurrence in the string, you need to split the string into parts first. I hope following snippet will be helpful to you.

```
String lletres = "BBB";
int lastIndex = lletres.lastIndexOf('B');
lletres = lletres.substring(0, lastIndex) + 'C' + lletres.substring(lastIndex+1);
```

This code will find index of last letter B and stores it in lastIndex. Then it splits the string and replaces that B letter with C letter.

Please keep in mind that this snippet doesn't check whether or not the letter B is present in the string.

With slight modification you can get it to replace whole parts of the string, not only letters. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
class Rplce
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String codi = "CCC";
String lletres = "BBB";
int char_no_to_be_replaced = 2;
lletres = lletres.substring(0,char_no_to_be_replaced ) + codi.charAt(codi.indexOf(lletres.charAt(char_no_to_be_replaced )) + 1) + lletres.substring(char_no_to_be_replaced + 1);
System.out.println(lletres);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this to replace the last character

```
  lletres = lletres.replaceAll(".{1}$", String.valueOf((char) (lletres.charAt(2) + 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have dynamic value at last index  and you want to replace that value will increasing one then use this code

```
   String lletres = "BBB";
   int atIndex = lletres.lastIndexOf('B');
   char ReplacementChar = (char)(lletres.charAt(lletres.lastIndexOf('B'))+1);
   lletres= lletres.substring(0, atIndex)+ReplacementChar;
   System.out.println(lletres);
```

**output**

BBC